# HQL / JPQL - Nested select on FROM

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql, jpql

I try to convert my SQL query into HQL or JPQL (I want to benefit of the object mapping).

My SQL Request is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT bde, MAX(creation_date) 
      FROM push_campaign GROUP BY bde) temp, 
push_campaign pc where pc.bde = temp.bde and pc.creation_date = temp.creation_date;
```

I try (unsuccessfully) to convert it in JPQL with :

```
select pc 
from (select bde, max(creationDate) 
      from PushCampaign group by bde) temp, 
PushCampaign pc 
where pc.bde = temp.bde and pc.creationDate = temp.creationDate
```

But I got raised :

> ```
> IllegalArgumentException occured :
> ```
>
> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near
>   line 1, column 16 [select pc from (select id, max(creationDate) from
>   models.PushCampaign group by bde) temp, models.PushCampaign pc where
>   pc.id = temp.id]

I read the nested select can only be in select or where clause.

Do you have workarounds to keep the request and benefit of object-mapping ?

Comment: Have you tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of joining in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have search how to but I can't find any example with subquery and innerjoin. All the tests I tried failed... Thanks for the hint, I ll dig in that direction

Comment: It is not possible to have subqueries in an inner join in jpql. It is only possible in where or having statements....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible with JPQL or HQL in a single request.

To do this in a single request I propose this :

```
String campaignToLaunch = "select pc.* from PushCampaign pc ..."
//SQL request which return a resultset compatible with the models.PushCampaign class
Class className = Class.forName("models.PushCampaign");
List<PushCampaign> result = JPA.em()
                           .createNativeQuery(campaignToLaunch,className)
                           .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 4):

this should achive similar results

```
select pc
from PushCampaign pc 
where pc.creationDate =
(select max(creationDate) from PushCampaign inner where inner.bde = pc.bde)
```

Comment: In fact I need a single record for each population "bde". Your request does not permit it. And, in fact different/a single population can have the same creationDate.

Comment: @kheraud your answer may be the more efficient but my query *does* return a record for each bde. For each record the subquery will look for the max date for the current bde only so the result of the subquery varies for each record and it should return the correct results. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be:

```
servlet
{
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SQL");
    List<> li =  q.getResultList();

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="UNIT")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```